# Extract company contact details from google

Tags: python, ruby, regex, email

My boss has given me a list of around 3500 companies and wants the generic contact email for each of them by tomorrow. I know this sounds retarded, and it is, but our client is demanding it. The approach I'd like to take is this:

- Carry out a google search for company name
- Identify company website and redirect to it
- Step through website links to find a contact us / about us page
- Locate and return the first email address on the page

I've done a bit of python here and there, but nothing web based or with regex... though I get the basic ideas I don't know if I would be able to execute this in the next 12 hours.

If anyone has any help on how I could script this with python or ruby I would be very appreciative......

Comment: I hate to say it, but this isn't a reasonable request to do in 12 hours if you haven't done it before.

Comment: you're going to really struggle to *automatically* find a 'contact us' page on any given webpage. If you're going this route, might be better to query google maps, which normally gives address and phone information in the result.

Comment: +1 @samb8s, trying to find the appropriate link on a page is difficult, and will most likely result in a lot of dead-ends or spiraling out of control because there is no standard for a "Contact Us" page designation.

Comment: Well, it is clear that your boss' request is not reasonable. But if you hadn't called it retarded, there was a good chance that you could have used the answers given here as a justification of why expecting to finish the task in 12 hours was not realistic. In any case, I second bcarlso's suggestion of crowdsourcing and using MTurk (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866851/252684).

Answer (score 4):

I would look to a more non-technical solution. You could split out the 3500 names and post them to Amazon Mechanical Turk as a HIT, paying 1 cent for each. Then instead writing code to scrape Google, you write code to create the hits and let real people do the "scraping" of the company websites.

Don't know if that will work for you but that's probably what I'd do.

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you'll probably want to look at using [Google's Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html), along with the [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) gem. Ruby's [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/) library, or the [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) gem will be useful. Also, Ruby's [Open::URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) or something like [Curb](http://rubygems.org/gems/curb) or [Typhoeus](http://rubygems.org/gems/typhoeus) will help.

You don't want to scrape Google's pages. They have an API for returning usable responses without the scraping and if you try to scrape 3500 searches I wouldn't be surprised if they ban you well before you're done.

Actual code samples to do what you want are in the docs for the libraries and gems.